# Get property value from type with inheritance

Tags: c#, interface

I have some types, which inherits from simple interface with ID getter.
I use this types in register in manager, like

```
Register<OpenDocumentLink>("DOCUMENT_OPEN");
```

and creation:

```
var ruleId = "DOCUMENT_OPEN";
MakeNewLink(ruleId);
```

**I want to access ID getter from type**, like:

```
Register<OpenDocumentLink>(OpenDocumentLink.ID);
```

and it should be **required** by compiler to implement ID getter in each class.

Some code:

```
public interface ILink
{
    string ID { get; }
    void Execute();
}

class OpenDocumentLink : ILink
{
    public string ID
    {
        get { return "DOCUMENT_OPEN"; }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `Register<OpenDocumentLink>(new OpenDocumentLink().ID);`

Comment: Have you considered making it Static?

Comment: Yep, i discussed it, but it won't make it required by compiler. And (for  Khanh TO) if it is possible, i prefer to avoid making additional instances just for checking ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically want is a "static" interface, which would mean something like

```
interface ILink
{
    static string ID { get; }
}
class OpenDocumentLink : ILink
{
    public static string ID { get { return "DOCUMENT_OPEN"; } }
}
```

which, unfortunately, is impossible in C#. Could you consider something like a function such as

```
public void Register<TLink>(TLink link) where TLink : ILink
```

and then just pass a whole `new OpenDocumentLink` object? What seems strange to me is that you take a type parameter (`OpenDocumentLink`), and you also have to pass the ID string, but the ID string seems to be one-to-one with the type. That is, if you know the type, you'd also know the ID - so why do you pass the ID as a parameter?

Consider reevaluating exactly what you need from your type. Will you pass more info than just the ID? If so, pass an instance of a class that implements `ILink`. Is the ID the only parameter you need to pass? If so, maybe make an enum, e.g. `MakeNewLink(LinkId.OpenDocument)`.

If this is unhelpful, it would be nice to have more information about what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Later i will get some types from registered (by IDs exactly) and make instances, then i will call Execute() for each. At this moment after creation i won't need IDs. But i also need to populate it with data, so i shouldn't use one instance more than one time. We can say, each link is calling some methods with parameters

Comment: If I may clarify that last bit: When calling `Register<TLink>`, it stores the type of `TLink`. Then later, it does something like `Activator.CreateInstance<TLink>()` and calls `Execute` on the resulting instance?
And also, if you had something like a `public static ID`, you wouldn't have to pass the ID as a parameter - you could just get `TLink.ID`?

Comment: Correct. But by static ID we can't make it required

Comment: Enum is great idea for me. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no "magic" solution. If you want your field to be accessible through the class instance, you need the property to be static. However, inheritance or interfaces do not work with static types in C#.

The simple answer would be: You need to implement it through governance. You may use an attribute for this or a static property. If you choose an attribute, you may use reflection upon the launch of your application to discover those modules and register only valid ones (or throw exceptions at runtime). You may also use something in the likes of Lint (FxCop) to make sure the rule is always followed.

Comment: "inheritance (...) cannot work with static types for obvious reasons" - given that some other OO languages such as Delphi do support that, this is kind of a strong claim. I suggest rewording to "C# does not support inheritance or interfaces with static members".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I made the correction. I was not aware this could be possible.